# Get a number from an array different from the one in it

Tags: javascript

I have an arrays, it can have different numbers or empty

```
[4,2] // here I need 0
[0,1,2] // here I need 3
[] // here I need 0
[1,2,4,7] // here I need 0
[0,5,3] // here I need 1
[0,1,2,3,5] // here I need 4
```

I need to get a number different from the numbers that are in the array, if some number is skipped get it, if the numbers are in order I need to get the biggest number +1.

**This is my solution but i think it's bad**

```
 let arr = [];
     let arrSort = arr.sort();
      let number = null;
      for (let i = 0; i < arrSort.length; i++) {
        if (arrSort.indexOf(i) === -1) {
          number = i;
        }
      }
      if (number === null) {
        number = arrSort.length;
      }
      console.log(number)
```

I tried several options already, but they turn out to be very large, I thought maybe you would advise which thread is a simple option?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this?

Comment: yes, but it turns out a lot of code with sorts, loops, etc., I thought that I would be advised which thread is a simple option or maybe there is already a ready-made method

Comment: please share what u did or you can explain you logic

Comment: Why was this closed as needs more focus? The question being asked is perfectly clear and OP is only asking how to do one thing. The only thing missing is a code example which is 'Needs more detail or clarity' at worst or a downvote.

Comment: If you sort the list, then iterate through each element, you'll be able to detect when the next number isn't 1 higher than the previous. At this point you'll have your result. This can be done in about 7-12 lines of code.

Comment: I added my code please see it

Comment: Instead of calling `indexOf`, you can check that `arrSort[i] === i`

Comment: If the question was closed 17 mins ago, how did I post my answer 1 min ago. Bug of SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to achieve this.

```js
var getNextNumber = (arr) => arr.length === 0 ? 0 : arr.sort().reduce((acc, el, i) => {
  return acc !== -1 ? acc : el !== i ? i : i === arr.length-1 ? arr.length : -1;
}, -1);

console.log(getNextNumber([]));
console.log(getNextNumber([0,1,2,4,5]));
console.log(getNextNumber([0,1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Comment: I think this is better than mine, as I wanted you to use only one method, than I have a bunch of checks thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store zero and increment for each value if equal.

This approach works with a short circuit and it does not need to visit all values, if not necessary.

```js
function getNext(array) {
    var value = 0;
    array.every(v => v === value && ++value);
    return value;
}
 
console.log(getNext([4, 2]));          // 0
console.log(getNext([0, 1, 2]));       // 3
console.log(getNext([]));              // 0
console.log(getNext([1, 2, 4, 7]));    // 0
console.log(getNext([0, 5, 3]));       // 1
console.log(getNext([0, 1, 2, 3, 5])); // 4
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```